# vb.net registry writing, and process issue

Tags: vb.net, windows, process, registry

I made an app in vb.net that needs to write a value to the registry and check for the path of the running process's files, i changed the manifest and made the app always run as admin with this line

```
     <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

but i still have a probleme, the app can't write to the registry due to 'permissions' and can't acces process's file path

here is the code i use to look for the process

```
            Dim proces() As System.Diagnostics.Process
            proces = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses
            For Each PR As System.Diagnostics.Process In proces
                If PR.MainModule.FileName = silentpath Then           
            ' i get an error in the if line saying that a 32bit process can't acces to a 64bit process modules
                    PR.Kill()
                End If
            Next
```

and here is the code i use to write to the registry

```
My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True).SetValue("myapp", apppath)
```

Comment: Does it work if you run the program as administrator?

Comment: The "requestedExecutionLevel" has to do with the UAC (User Account Control) stuff which is NOT the same as permissions assigned through your network admin. Are you logged into the computer as a user that has the "Administrator" role on the local box?

Comment: i'm logged as an admin, and i solved the registry probleme it depended on the key i wanted to add, but the process problemis still there, basically what i'm trying to do is to look for the process id for that is running from a selected file (the exe path) and kill it,i don't want to search by name as there maybe other processes with the same name